# Comparar valores de dos listas

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo dos archivos de texto con el siguiente contenido:

**local.txt:**

```
STRING001 ID123
STRING002 ID124
STRING003 ID125
STRING004 ID126
```

**recv.txt:**

```
STRING003 ID126
```

Contando con estos dos ficheros y su contenido, me gustaría obtener un tercer archivo llamado `final.txt`, el contenido debería ser el siguiente:

```
STRING001 ID123
STRING002 ID124
STRING003 ID126
```

La lógica para obtener el contenido del fichero `final.txt` es comparando el contenido de los dos archivos que tengo guardado en una lista. Lo que se debe tener en cuenta es el valor de **STRING**, si en los dos está el valor 003 pero el **ID** es diferente, se debe guardar la string recibida en el `final.txt`. Si los valores existentes en el `local.txt` no tienen otro valor en el otro archivo, se deben guardar tal cual.
Tengo el siguiente código en el qual estoy guardando el valor de **STRING** como posición y el valor de **ID**:

```
import re

localFile = open("C:\\local.txt","r+")
recvFile = open("C:\\recv.txt","r")
finalFile = open("C:\\final.txt","r")

posicionesListLocal = []
identificadoresListLocal = []

posicionesListRecv = []
identificadoresListRecv = []

conjuntoValoresLocales = []
conjuntoValoresRecv = []

for line in localFile:
    posicion = re.compile("STRING(\d+)")
    identificador = re.compile("ID(\d+)")
    
    conjunto = re.compile("STRING(\d+).ID(\d+)")
    
    if line:
        pos = posicion.search(line)
        ide = identificador.search(line)
        
        conj = conjunto.search(line)
        conjuntoValores = (conj.group())
        conjuntoValoresLocales.append(conjuntoValores)

        posicionesListLocal.append(pos.group())
        identificadoresListLocal.append(ide.group())

for line in recvFile:
    posicion = re.compile("STRING(\d+)")
    identificador = re.compile("ID(\d+)")

    conjunto = re.compile("STRING(\d+).ID(\d+)")
    
    if line:
        pos = posicion.search(line)
        ide = identificador.search(line)

        conj = conjunto.search(line)
        conjuntoValores = (conj.group())
        conjuntoValorsRecv.append(conjuntoValores)
        
        posicionesListRecv.append(pos.group())
        identificadoresListRecv.append(ide.group())

print (conjuntoValoresLocales)
print (conjuntoValoresRecv)
```

He intentado comparar el contenido de las dos listas, pero no puedo llegar a guardar correctamente el contenido en el archivo final usando `finalFile.write` ya que no comprendo como comparar los valores de las dos listas de valores.

Si alguien me puede indicar como realizarlo se lo agradecería. Gracias de antemano!

Comment: `finalFile = open("C:\\final.txt","r")` La has abierto en modo lectura, probaste a cambiar esa `r` por una `w`?

Comment: El problema no es que no escriba en el archivo si no que no comprendo como realizar la diferencia entre las strings de cada fichero para obtener el resultado que indico.

Comment: Cito textualmente de tu pregunta: *pero no puedo llegar a guardar correctamente el contenido en el archivo final usando finalFile.write* -> Como entenderás, para quienes no estamos delante de tu código viendo lo que pasa, esa frase da a entender que tienes problemas para *guardar* el archivo :)

Comment: Cierto, ya lo he modificado, gracias por la puntualización!

Comment: Por qué en el archivo final no aparece `STRING004`? Estaba en el archivo inicial y no obtuvo otro valor del archivo `recv.txt` ¿no debería estar entonces en el final?

Answer (score 1):

Creo que hay algunas cosas que quizás no tomaste en cuenta:

- Para que la última línea no esté repetida hay que comparar también la segunda parte de la string. Si solamente comparas la primera parte el resultado en el archivo final sería:

  ```
    STRING001 ID123
    STRING002 ID124
    STRING003 ID126
    STRING004 ID126
  ```
- Hay que contemplar el caso en el que el número en `STRING000` no corresponda a ninguno de los existentes (en mi ejemplo lo agrego a la lista como un elemento nuevo).
- Los 3 archivos que usas se quedan abiertos. Sobre todo al trabajar con tantos archivos es recomendable utilizar `with open()` el cual cierra automáticamente los archivos al terminar las operaciones.

No utilicé la librería `re` en mi ejemplo con el objetivo de facilitar la comprensión del código.

```
with open('local.txt','r') as f1, open('recv.txt','r') as f2, open('final.txt','w+') as f3:
    # Lee los datos
    data1 = f1.read().splitlines()
    data2 = f2.read().splitlines()

    # Compara los datos
    for d2 in data2:
        l1, l2 = d2.split() # separa la string en 2
        for d1 in data1:
            r1, r2 = d1.split()
            i = data1.index(d1) # obtiene el index
            if r1 == l1: # compara la primera parte de la string
                data1[i] = d2 # sobreescrive el elemento
            if r2 == l2: # compara la segunda parte de la string
                del data1[i] # elimina el elemento
        if not any(l1 in c for c in data1): # elemento nuevo
            data1.append(d2) # agrega el elemento

    # Salva el resultado
    f3.writelines('\n'.join(data1))
```

El código anterior crea el archivo `final.txt` con el siguiente contenido:

```
STRING001 ID123
STRING002 ID124
STRING003 ID126
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta. Realmente si todas las líneas tienen el mismo formato, creo que el uso de expresiones regulares sería más lento que un split *normal*. Por cierto, he editado tu pregunta para modificar el `while open` a `with open` ya que creo que te equivocaste al escribirlo, no? :) Un saludo!

Comment: Si, me equivoqué, muchas gracias.